# extract specific field by index from json string stored in dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that contains json style dictionaries per row, and I need to extract the fourth and eigth fields, or values from the second and fourth pairs to a new column i.e. 'a' for row 1, 'a' for 2 (corresponding to the *Group*) and '10786' for row 1, '38971' for row 2 (corresponding to *Code*). The expected output is below.

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': ['{"Number":1,"Group":"a","First":"Yes","Code":"10786","Desc":true,"Labs":"["a","b","c"]"}',
                          '{"Number":2,"Group":"a","First":"Yes","Code":"38971","Desc":true,"Labs":"["a","b","c"]"}']})
```

expected output

```
                                                   a Group   Code
0  {"Number":1,"Group":"a","First":"Yes","Second"...     a  10786
1  {"Number":2,"Group":"a","First":"Yes","Second"...     a  38971
```

I have tried indexing by location but its printing only characters rather than fields e.g.

```
tuple(dat['a'].items())[0][1][4]
```

I also cannot appear to normalize the data with json_normalize, which I'm not sure why - perhaps the json string is stored suboptimally. So I am quite confused, and any tips would be great. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `pd.json_normalize` is not working is because `pd.json_normalize` works on dictionaries and your strings are not json compatible.

Your strings are not json compatible because the "Labs" values contain multiple quotes which aren't escaped.
It's possible to write a quick function to make your strings json compatible, then parse them as dictionaries, and finally use `pd.json_normalize`.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

jsonify = lambda x: re.sub(pattern='"Labs":"(.*)"', repl='"Labs":\g<1>', string=x) # Function to remove unnecessary quotes

dat = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': ['{"Number":1,"Group":"a","First":"Yes","Code":"10786","Desc":true,"Labs":"["a","b","c"]"}',
                          '{"Number":2,"Group":"a","First":"Yes","Code":"38971","Desc":true,"Labs":"["a","b","c"]"}']})

json_series = dat['col1'].apply(jsonify) # Remove unnecessary quotes
json_series = json_series.apply(json.loads) # Convert string to dictionary
output = pd.json_normalize(json_series) # "Flatten" the dictionary into columns
output.insert(loc=0, column='a', value=dat['col1']) # Add the original column as a column named "a" because that's what the question requests.
```

|  | a | Number | Group | First | Code | Desc | Labs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | {"Number":1,"Group":"a","First":"Yes","Code":"10786","Desc":true,"Labs":"["a","b","c"]"} | 1 | a | Yes | 10786 | True | ['a', 'b', 'c'] |
| 1 | {"Number":2,"Group":"a","First":"Yes","Code":"38971","Desc":true,"Labs":"["a","b","c"]"} | 2 | a | Yes | 38971 | True | ['a', 'b', 'c'] |